# Почему не очищается содержимое тега

Tags: jquery

Вот html код

```
<p class="col-lg-24 col-md-24 col-sm-24 col-xs-24 color">
<span class="fa fa-square fa-4x colorinput" style="color:#ff9900" data-color="91822"></span>
<span class="fa fa-square fa-4x colorinput" style="color:#4a86e8" data-color="91823"></span>
</p>
```

Таким образом создаю элемент`<strong class="fa fa-times-circle colorinputremove"></strong>`

```
$('.colorinput').click(function () {
        var colorId = $(this).attr('data-color');
        console.log(colorId);
        var addIcon='<strong class="fa fa-times-circle colorinputremove"></strong>';
        $(this).html(addIcon);
    });
```

таким образом пытаюсь удалить созданный объект - объект `<strong class="fa fa-times-circle colorinputremove"></strong>`

```
$(".colorinput").on('click','colorinputremove',function () {
    var colorId = $(this).parent('.colorinput').attr('data-color');
    console.log(colorId);
    $(this).parent('.colorinput').empty();
})
```

но он не удаётся его удалить. Тем не менее следующий код:

```
var colorId = $(this).parent('.colorinput').attr('data-color');
console.log(colorId);
```

в консоль выводит цифры, находящиеся в атрибуте `data-color` родителя элемента. Ожидался вывод `data-color` родителя элемента и удаление элемента.

Comment: добавь `console.log` в обе функции и увидишь, что при клике они обе вызываются

Comment: а, у тебя даже есть логи, только они одно и то же выводят

Comment: а еще добавь `html` и напиши, что значит _он не удаётся его удалить но это отрабатывает_ - какой результат ожидается и какой есть на самом деле?

Comment: @Grundy Так понятно?  Изменил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, вы забыли добавить точку для поиска классов.

```
/// .colorinputremove
$(".colorinput").on('click','.colorinputremove',function () { ... });
```

Но даже в таком случае, элемент сначала удалится и потом снова будет создан. Не забывайте, что происходит процесс всплытия события, который надо останавливать через `e.stopPropagation()`.

```js
$('.colorinput').click(function () {
    var colorId = $(this).attr('data-color');
    var addIcon='<strong class="fa fa-times-circle colorinputremove">click me</strong>';
    $(this).html(addIcon);
});

$(".colorinput").on('click','.colorinputremove',function (e) {
  
    var colorId = $(this).parent('.colorinput').attr('data-color');
    $(this).parent('.colorinput').empty();
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

```css
.colorinput
{
  width:200px;
  height: 20px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.colorinputremove
{
  outline: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="col-lg-24 col-md-24 col-sm-24 col-xs-24 color">
<div class="fa fa-square fa-4x colorinput" style="color:#ff9900" data-color="91822"></div>
<div class="fa fa-square fa-4x colorinput" style="color:#4a86e8" data-color="91823"></div>
</p>
```

Comment: проблема не в том, что он создается или удаляется он вообще не удаляется.

Comment: @Sergalas, _вы забыли добавить точку для поиска классов._

Comment: @Sergalas, Вы внимательно прочитали ответ и ознакомились с примером, в котором все работает?

Comment: как оказалось не доконца спасибо все работает.

Comment: @AlexKrass, стоит полужирным выделить ту строчку :-)

Comment: @Grundy, к сожалению полужирный и красивое выделение кода не работают вместе. Что-то я не догадался сразу выставить данное предложение с выделением полужирным и отдельно оформленный код.

Comment: @AlexKrass, я имел ввиду текст, который я в комментарий скопировал

Comment: @Grundy, да, я понял, просто у меня было желание сделать это так: _вы забыли добавить точку для поиска классов $(".colorinput").on('click',**'.colorinputremove'**,function () { ... });_ Но что-то мне не понравился код текстом и в итоге сам запутался и главное не выделил.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".colorinput").on('click','colorinputremove', ... );
```

Перед `colorinputremove` надо поставить точку, чтобы получился селектор класса и получилось:

```
$(".colorinput").on('click','.colorinputremove', ... );
```

Comment: не сраслось не удалеятся